# Viewing previously viewed pages of same tab in Firefox

Tags: firefox

In Firefox, the user can click and hold on the back arrow button to see the history of the current tab.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that does the same thing, i.e. opens this panel of previously viewed pages?

Comment: no https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly but you could write a script that creates it

Comment: Not exactly -- but Ctrl-Shift-T opens a previously closed tab, and hitting the back button should replay its history.